# Is it possible to store images with labels in GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, deep-learning, gridfs, nosql

I'm working on a Deep Learning project. I have many URL. I want to store images with labels(categories) on a NoSQL Database. I stored images on GridFS but I don't find any information about image and text storing in GridFS. Is it possible to store images with its labels in GridFS? If it is possible, how can I store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store metadata with image. Like this :

```
ApplicationContext ctx =
                 new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class);
GridFsOperations gridOperations =
                  (GridFsOperations) ctx.getBean("gridFsTemplate");

DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
metaData.put("extra1", "anything 1");
metaData.put("extra2", "anything 2");

InputStream inputStream = null;

inputStream = new FileInputStream("image path");
gridOperations.store(inputStream, "testing.png", "image/png", metaData);
```

or you can store text file as a another mongodb object. More info :

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_relationships.htm